# Need to verify I am understanding SQL Logic

Tags: sql-server, logic

I would like to know if I have this SQL logic decoded correctly.  Here is the the SQL:

```
,[hrs].[Hours] - SUM(CASE WHEN [UnitState].[UnitStateType] <> 'ACTIVE' THEN [Allocation].[AllocatedEnergyMwh] ELSE 0 END / CAST([Unit].[NetDependableCapacity] AS FLOAT)) AS SH
```

I interpret this as saying:

```
if [UnitState].[UnitStateType] does not equal active then SH equals the sum of [Allocation].[AllocatedEnergyMwh] / 
    (float)[Unit].[NetDependableCapacity].  

else SH = [hrs].[Hours]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly.

There is no *else* for SH.  The else only affects the sum aggregate.  More accurately, it says:

```
SH = hours -
 (the sum of AllocatedEnergyMwh where StateType != ACTIVE) / NetDependableCapacity
```

The else is only used to ignore the active AllocatedEnergyMwh in the sum. It does this by setting AllocatedEnergyMwh = 0 in those cases.

Answer (score 1):

It's close but you missed the [hrs].[Hours] - case part for the first one.

```
if [UnitState].[UnitStateType] does not equal active
    then SH equals [hrs].[Hours] minus the sum of [Allocation].[AllocatedEnergyMwh] / (float)[Unit].[NetDependableCapacity].  

else SH = [hrs].[Hours] minus (0)/[Unit].[NetDependableCapacity]
```

Answer (score 1):

if [UnitState].[UnitStateType]  does not equal active then

[hrs].[Hours]  minus sum([Allocation].[AllocatedEnergyMwh] / [Unit].[NetDependableCapacity])

otherwise

[hrs].[Hours]  minus sum(0/[Unit].[NetDependableCapacity]) -->meaning [hrs].[Hours] - 0